# Add method not showing all fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

When i click on add, it should show all fields to fill, but it doesn't. It is showing 'idIntervaloHorario' and 'Cita' instead of 'idIntervaloHorario', 'Cita', 'numeroVehiculos'. Maybe it's a stupid thing but i'm unable to find the problem.

**Controller**

```
public function citas_lista() {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        //CONDICIONES DE ADMINISTRADOR-------------------------------------------------------//

        if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
            $crud->unset_delete();
            $crud->unset_edit();
            //Tratando de obtener el usuario logeado
            // $username = $this->session->userdata( 'username' );
            $datos = array(
                'title' => "Citas", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
                'username' => ""
            );

            $this->load->view('commons/header2', $datos);
        } else {

            $datos = array(
                'title' => "Citas", // En la vista 'header' tendré una variable $title
                'username' => "Administrador"
            );

            $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);
        }

//$crud->unset_bootstrap();
//---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/header.php'  ------------- /


        $crud->set_language("spanish");
        $crud->set_theme('flexigrid');
        $crud->set_table('citas');

        $crud->columns(array('idIntervaloHorario', 'cita', 'numeroVehiculos'));

        $crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'intervaloshorarios', 'intervaloHorario');
//Para cambiar los nombres de las columnas usar el display_as
        $crud->display_as('cita', 'Cita')
                ->display_as('idIntervaloHorario', 'Franja Horaria')
                ->display_as('numeroVehiculos', 'Plazas Ocupadas (Límite 4)');

        $crud->callback_column('cita', array($this, '_callback_intervalo_horario'));

//Para el botón añadir
        $crud->set_subject('Cita');
//Esta regla establece que no se pueden añadir líneas con intervalos 
//y fechas en líneas duplicadas
        //PARA LAS INSERCIONES DUPLICADAS (NO FUNCIONA)
        //$crud->set_rules('intervaloHorario', 'Franja Horaria', '_callback_doublerow_check');
        //$crud->set_rules('citas', 'Franja Horaria', 'doublerow_check');


        if ($this->Fechacita_Model->get_duplicaterow()) {
            echo 'La última fila insertada ya existe, por favor póngase en contacto con el administrador '
            . 'para más información';
        }

        $this->Fechacita_Model->delete_duplicaterow();








        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);

//---------------   Cargo la vista 'commons/footer.php'  ------------- /
        $this->load->view('commons/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `$crud->fields(//database fields);` to show the field, but using set_relation should be enought. Anyway, i'll leave this answer here.